# Is KineticJS capable of performing smooth animations with many objects using the move method?

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to animate many objects to a canvas using KineticJS. I am using the built-in move method on every frame. It is known that redrawing a layer is an expensive operation which can cause performance issues, so I am calling layer.draw() only after each move operations has already been executed. Despite this, the more objects I animate, the poor the performance becomes and the end result is a sluggish animation.

To compare the KineticJS performance against the native canvas, I prepared two demos that do the same thing - bouncing balls in a canvas of 500x500. The first one is using the native canvas. It just clears the canvas on each frame and draws the balls. The second one uses KineticJS and once the image objects are created, it uses the move method to move them.

It is obvious that while the native demo performs the same with 10, 100 and 1000 balls, the performance of KineticJS demo is strongly affected by the number of balls. With 1000, it is just unusable. There are many optimizations that can be made to both examples, including using requestAnimationFrame for animation loop or using the built-in Animation object for KineticJS, but these will not change the performance of the demos much.

So here are the two demos. First, the native one - http://jsfiddle.net/uxsLN/1/

```
(function() {

    window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);

    function loaded() {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = canvasApp;
        img.src = 'ball.png';
    }

    function canvasApp() {

        var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

        function drawScreen() {

            context.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);

            context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            context.strokeRect(1, 1, theCanvas.width - 2, theCanvas.height - 2);

            context.fillStyle = "#000000";

            var ball;
            for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                ball = balls[i];
                ball.x += ball.xunits;
                ball.y += ball.yunits;
                context.drawImage(img, ball.x, ball.y);
                if (ball.x + ball.radius * 2 > theCanvas.width || ball.x < 0) {
                    ball.angle = 180 - ball.angle;
                    updateBall(ball);
                } else if (ball.y + ball.radius * 2 > theCanvas.height || ball.y < 0) {
                    ball.angle = 360 - ball.angle;
                    updateBall(ball);
                }
            }
        }

        function updateBall(ball) {
            ball.radians = ball.angle * Math.PI / 180;
            ball.xunits = Math.cos(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
            ball.yunits = Math.sin(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
        }

        var numBalls = 1000;
        var maxSize = 8;
        var minSize = 5;
        var maxSpeed = maxSize + 5;
        var balls = [];
        var radius = 24;

        for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {

            var speed = maxSpeed - radius;
            var angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
            var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;

            var ball = {
                x : (theCanvas.width - radius) / 2,
                y : (theCanvas.height - radius) / 2,
                radius : radius,
                speed : speed,
                angle : angle,
                xunits : Math.cos(radians) * speed,
                yunits : Math.sin(radians) * speed
            }

            balls.push(ball);
        }

        function gameLoop() {
            window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
            drawScreen()
        }
        gameLoop();
    }

})();
```

Next, KineticJS - http://jsfiddle.net/MNpUX/

```
(function() {

    window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);

    function loaded() {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = canvasApp;
        img.src = 'ball.png';
    }

    function canvasApp() {

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container : 'container',
            width : 500,
            height : 500
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        stage.add(layer);

        rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x : 0,
            y : 0,
            width : stage.getWidth(),
            height : stage.getHeight(),
            fill : '#EEEEEE',
            stroke : 'black'
        });

        layer.add(rect);

        function drawScreen() {

            var ball;
            for ( var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                ball = balls[i];
                ball.obj.move(ball.xunits, ball.yunits);
                if (ball.obj.getX() + ball.radius * 2 > stage.getWidth() || ball.obj.getX() < 0) {
                    ball.angle = 180 - ball.angle;
                    updateBall(ball);
                } else if (ball.obj.getY() + ball.radius * 2 > stage.getHeight() || ball.obj.getY() < 0) {
                    ball.angle = 360 - ball.angle;
                    updateBall(ball);
                }
            }
            layer.draw();
        }

        function updateBall(ball) {
            ball.radians = ball.angle * Math.PI / 180;
            ball.xunits = Math.cos(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
            ball.yunits = Math.sin(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
        }

        var numBalls = 1000;
        var maxSize = 8;
        var minSize = 5;
        var maxSpeed = maxSize + 5;
        var balls = [];
        var radius = 24;
        for ( var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
            var speed = maxSpeed - radius;
            var angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
            var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
            var obj = new Kinetic.Image({
                image : img,
                x : (stage.getWidth() - radius) / 2,
                y : (stage.getHeight() - radius) / 2
            });
            layer.add(obj);
            var ball = {
                radius : radius,
                speed : speed,
                angle : angle,
                xunits : Math.cos(radians) * speed,
                yunits : Math.sin(radians) * speed,
                obj : obj
            };
            balls.push(ball);
        }

        function gameLoop() {
            window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
            drawScreen()
        }
        gameLoop();
    }

})();
```

So the question is - do I miss something about KineticJS or it is just not built for such a purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can gain a little speed by:**

- Turning listening off on the stage.
- Using layer.drawScene instead of layer.draw. (drawScene doesn't also redraw the hit scene).
- Reducing the ball count to 500 (the effect looks pretty much the same).

**If your design permits, use a custom Kinetic.Shape to get "closer to the metal".**

The Kinetic.Shape gives you a wrapped Context on which you can run native Context commands.

Using Shape, you'll get magnitudes better results because there's only 1 object being managed.

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/AVJyr/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          listening:false
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      //
      var cw=stage.getWidth();
      var ch=stage.getHeight();
      var numBalls = 1000;
      var maxSize = 8;
      var minSize = 5;
      var maxSpeed = maxSize + 5;
      var balls = [];
      var radius = 24;
      // this is a custom Kinetic.Shape
      var shape;


      for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
          var speed = maxSpeed - radius;
          var angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
          var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
          var ball = {
            x : (cw-radius)/2,
            y : (ch-radius)/2,
            radius : radius,
            speed : speed,
            angle : angle,
            xunits : Math.cos(radians) * speed,
            yunits : Math.sin(radians) * speed
          }
          balls.push(ball);
      }

      // load the ball image and create the Kinetic.Shape
      img = new Image();
      img.onload=function(){

          shape=new Kinetic.Shape({
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              width:500,
              height:500,
              draggable: true,
              drawFunc: function(context) {
                  context.beginPath();
                  var ball;
                  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                    ball = balls[i];
                    ball.x += ball.xunits;
                    ball.y += ball.yunits;
                    context.drawImage(img, ball.x, ball.y);
                    if (ball.x+ball.radius*2>cw || ball.x<0) {
                      ball.angle = 180 - ball.angle;
                    } else if (ball.y+ball.radius*2>ch || ball.y<0) {
                      ball.angle = 360 - ball.angle;
                    }
                    ball.radians = ball.angle * Math.PI / 180;
                    ball.xunits = Math.cos(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
                    ball.yunits = Math.sin(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
                  }
                  context.fillStrokeShape(this);
              },
          });
          layer.add(shape);

          // GO!
          gameLoop();
      }
      img.src = 'http://users-cs.au.dk/mic/dIntProg/e12/uge/4/Projekter/bouncingballs/assignment/ball.png';

      // RAF used to repeatedly redraw the custom shape
      function gameLoop(){
          window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
          layer.clear();
          shape.draw();
      }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So do you recommend to avoid the move method and use the native context for such purposes? This can really solve the performance issues, but in the same time you lose most of the KineticJS functionality and the abstraction. Given the bouncing ball example, you are no longer able to interact with each ball as if they are "real" objects.

Comment: Your design requirements determine what solution you apply.  Keep in mind that since each ball is a separate object, you can still interact with them (hit-test, adjust properties, etc). In the end, you're facing a trade-off: native canvas speed vs Kinetic easy object management.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: +1.  I'd also like to point out that KineticJS will support a new high performance mode that doesn't include node nesting, transforms, event handling, event firing, etc.  For people with simple use cases, this will be ideal, and will accomplish near native rendering speeds.  This will be released as v5.1.0

Comment: @EricRowell Cool new feature...looking forward to 5.1.0 then!